# WebAudio: Steep lowpass?

Tags: lowpass-filter, web-audio-api

I made a HTML5 game that uses ADPCM samples and music.

The music itself is at 11025Hz mono and I made a simple nearest-Neighbour-Resampler to get 22050Hz plus a fake stereo algorithm.

The samples are pre-upsampled during loading to reduce CPU load during runtime (no realtime-resampling needed).

So I achieved that real retro-sound like in the late 90's.

Works fine so far.

But the "real" resampler of WebAudio that matches the 22050Hz to the internal sample rate seems to be not even better on some browsers :-D.

How can I chop off everything above 11025Hz (Nyquist frequency of 22050Hz)? Ideal would be: 0-11025Hz untouched but 11026Hz-max filtered out.

The low pass filter provided by the WebAudio api isn't steep enough and produces resonances at the filter frequency.

I don't want to allow the "crappy" frequencies going so high. The "crappy" resampling should stop at 11025Hz. I think, it isn't good to tweeter speakers and even the players hearing when the strong bass frequencies mirror at high frequency range.

Don't want MP3&Co here. ADPCM->MP3 needs more bitrate than real ADPCM (The desired artifacts of that are hard to encode without audible loss) :-).

I read about FIR and IIR filters but I didn't understand them because it is too mathematic to me.

I think, this is, what I need.

I need something that can be transformed to code without having a academic degree :-D.

Answer (score 0):

I'm likely late to the party, but to achieve a steeper filter curve, you simply need multiple applications of the biquad filter, i.e. multiple BiquadFilterNode objects chained together.

A single BiquadFilterNode with `lowpass` has a 12db per octave rolloff, from this you can easily calculate the number of filter nodes you need. If you are concerned about resonance, simply decrease it (`Q` setting).

Comment: I'm even later to the party, but unfortunately, even when setting Q to the lowest possible value, the lowpass (and highpass) still generate resonance. What I'm currently doing is adding another peaking filter after and trying to tune it to cancel out the unwanted resonance.